# How to utilize Flink's TestHarness class?

Tags: unit-testing, apache-flink

I need to test a CoFlatMapFunction that shares state. Through my reading I have come to conclusion I should use the TestHarness class per: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/testing.html#testing-checkpointing-and-state-handling

Since it is not apart of the public api, I cannot figure out how to import it without copy and pasting the class itself. I thought it maybe in flink-test-utils-junit, but it was not as well.

Comment: I m having the same problem. I cannot find the TestHarness classes for flink-test-utils, flink-streaming-java, flink-runtime, and flink-test-utils-junit. Flink version is 1.15.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add these 3 dependencies to your project (or the versions for scala 2.12, if that's the version of scala you're using):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-test-utils-junit</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <!-- with Flink 1.14+, this is flink-runtime -->
    <artifactId>flink-runtime_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>test-jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Note also that since Flink 1.14, the flink-runtime is scala-free, so with newer versions of Flink, remove the "_2.11" from the flink-runtime dependency.

The [Flink training exercises](https://github.com/apache/flink-training) include examples of tests that use harnesses, such as [RidesAndFaresUnitTest](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/rides-and-fares/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/training/exercises/ridesandfares/RidesAndFaresUnitTest.java).

Comment: Thanks this worked great! Is there any documentation anywhere that specifies this? I am wondering if I missed this or the documentation could be better.

Comment: No, there isn't any documentation for using the test harnesses. So far they aren't really supported, but are just offered on an as-is basis.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, the first link is offline now. Do you have an updated version? Thanks.

Comment: it does not work for scala - sbt is this only for java?

Comment: I've used these test harnesses to write tests in Java that test Scala applications, so I know that works. I haven't tried using the harnesses directly from Scala.

Answer (score 0):

I found David`s answer very useful but in Sbt you have to use this classifier to make it work:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-java" % flinkVersion % "test" classifier "tests",
```