# Is there a notion of virtual time in Apache Flink tests like there is in Reactor and RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, project-reactor

In RxJava and Reactor there is this notion of virtual time to tests operators that are dependent of time. I cant figure out how to do this in Flink. For example I have put together the following example where I would like to play around with late arriving events to understand how they are handled. However im not able to understand how such a test would look? Is there a way to combine Flink and Reactor to make the tests better?

```
public class PlayWithFlink {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final OutputTag<MyEvent> lateOutputTag = new OutputTag<MyEvent>("late-data"){};

        // TODO understand how BoundedOutOfOrderness is related to allowedLateness
        BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<MyEvent> eventTimeFunction = new BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<MyEvent>(Time.seconds(10)) {
            @Override
            public long extractTimestamp(MyEvent element) {
                return element.getEventTime();
            }
        };

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

        DataStream<MyEvent> events = env.fromCollection(MyEvent.examples())
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(eventTimeFunction);

        AggregateFunction<MyEvent, MyAggregate, MyAggregate> aggregateFn = new AggregateFunction<MyEvent, MyAggregate, MyAggregate>() {
            @Override
            public MyAggregate createAccumulator() {
                return new MyAggregate();
            }

            @Override
            public MyAggregate add(MyEvent myEvent, MyAggregate myAggregate) {
                if (myEvent.getTracingId().equals("trace1")) {
                    myAggregate.getTrace1().add(myEvent);
                    return myAggregate;
                }
                myAggregate.getTrace2().add(myEvent);
                return myAggregate;
            }

            @Override
            public MyAggregate getResult(MyAggregate myAggregate) {
                return myAggregate;
            }

            @Override
            public MyAggregate merge(MyAggregate myAggregate, MyAggregate acc1) {
                acc1.getTrace1().addAll(myAggregate.getTrace1());
                acc1.getTrace2().addAll(myAggregate.getTrace2());
                return acc1;
            }
        };

        KeySelector<MyEvent, String> keyFn = new KeySelector<MyEvent, String>() {
            @Override
            public String getKey(MyEvent myEvent) throws Exception {
                return myEvent.getTracingId();
            }
        };

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<MyAggregate> result = events
                .keyBy(keyFn)
                .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(10)))
                .allowedLateness(Time.seconds(20))
                .sideOutputLateData(lateOutputTag)
                .aggregate(aggregateFn);


        DataStream lateStream = result.getSideOutput(lateOutputTag);

        result.print("SessionData");

        lateStream.print("LateData");

        env.execute();
    }
}

class MyEvent {
    private final String tracingId;
    private final Integer count;
    private final long eventTime;

    public MyEvent(String tracingId, Integer count, long eventTime) {
        this.tracingId = tracingId;
        this.count = count;
        this.eventTime = eventTime;
    }

    public String getTracingId() {
        return tracingId;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public long getEventTime() {
        return eventTime;
    }

    public static List<MyEvent> examples() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        MyEvent e1 = new MyEvent("trace1", 1, now);
        MyEvent e2 = new MyEvent("trace2", 1, now);
        MyEvent e3 = new MyEvent("trace2", 1, now - 1000);
        MyEvent e4 = new MyEvent("trace1", 1, now - 200);
        MyEvent e5 = new MyEvent("trace1", 1, now - 50000);
        return Arrays.asList(e1,e2,e3,e4, e5);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyEvent{" +
                "tracingId='" + tracingId + '\'' +
                ", count=" + count +
                ", eventTime=" + eventTime +
                '}';
    }
}

class MyAggregate {
    private final List<MyEvent> trace1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<MyEvent> trace2 = new ArrayList<>();


    public List<MyEvent> getTrace1() {
        return trace1;
    }

    public List<MyEvent> getTrace2() {
        return trace2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyAggregate{" +
                "trace1=" + trace1 +
                ", trace2=" + trace2 +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The output of running this is:

```
SessionData:1> MyAggregate{trace1=[], trace2=[MyEvent{tracingId='trace2', count=1, eventTime=1551034666081}, MyEvent{tracingId='trace2', count=1, eventTime=1551034665081}]}
SessionData:3> MyAggregate{trace1=[MyEvent{tracingId='trace1', count=1, eventTime=1551034166081}], trace2=[]}
SessionData:3> MyAggregate{trace1=[MyEvent{tracingId='trace1', count=1, eventTime=1551034666081}, MyEvent{tracingId='trace1', count=1, eventTime=1551034665881}], trace2=[]}
```

However I would expect to see the lateStream trigger for the `e5` event that should be 50seconds before the first event triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your watermark assigner to be like this

```
AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks eventTimeFunction = new AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks<MyEvent>() {
    long maxTs = 0;

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(MyEvent myEvent, long l) {
        long ts = myEvent.getEventTime();
        if (ts > maxTs) {
            maxTs = ts;
        }
        return ts;
    }

    @Override
    public Watermark checkAndGetNextWatermark(MyEvent event, long extractedTimestamp) {
        return new Watermark(maxTs - 10000);
    }
};
```

then you will get the results you expect. I'm not recommending this -- just using it to illustrate what's going on.

What's happening here is that a `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` is a periodic watermark generator that will only insert a watermark into the stream every 200 msec (by default). Because your job completes long before then, the only watermark your job is experiencing is the one the Flink injects at the end of every finite stream (with value MAX_WATERMARK). Lateness is relative to watermarks, and the event that you expected to be late is managing to arrive before that watermark.

By switching to punctuated watermarks you can force watermarking to occur more often, or more precisely at specific points in the stream. This is generally unnecessary (and too frequent watermarking causes overhead), but is helpful when you want to have strong control over the sequencing of watermarks.

As for how to write tests, you might take a look at the [test harnesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717003/how-to-utilize-flinks-testharness-class) used in Flink's own tests, or at [flink-spector](https://github.com/ottogroup/flink-spector).

Update:

The time interval associated with the BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor is a specification of how out-of-order the stream is expected to be. Events that arrive within this bound are not considered late, and event time timers won't fire until this delay has elapsed, thereby giving time for out-of-order events to arrive. allowedLateness only applies to the window API, and describes for how long past the normal window firing time the framework keeps window state so that events can still be added to a window and cause late firings. After this additional interval, window state is cleared and subsequent events are sent to the side output (if configured).

[image]

So when you use `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<MyEvent>(Time.seconds(10))` you are *not* saying "wait 10 seconds after every event in case earlier events might still arrive". But you are saying that your events should be at most 10 seconds out of order. So if you are processing a live, real-time event stream, this means you will wait for *at most* 10 seconds in case earlier events arrive. (And if you are processing historic data, then you may be able to process 10 seconds of data in 1 second, or not -- knowing you will wait for n seconds of event time to pass says nothing about how long it will actually take.)

For more on this topic, see [Event Time and Watermarks](https://training.ververica.com/lessons/event-time-watermarks.html).

Comment: Ok so there is no way to simulate the time of the watermarks, it would be nice in test to be able to fully control how watermarks are generated. For example I wanted to write test just so that I could test the BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor. What I want to know is how it affects the notion of lateness in the stream. For example if I have a BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor  with 10 seconds and an allowedLateness of 10 seconds what would be a late message then? Is it if it arrives 20 seconds after the last timestamp of 10 seconds after the last timestamp?

Comment: The test harnesses and flink-spector provide ways to control watermarks for testing, but perhaps not in the way you are looking for. Lateness is relative to the watermarks -- an allowedLateness of 10 seconds will permit processing of records whose timestamps are at most 10 seconds behind (less than) the current watermark.

Comment: Yes but also the BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor specify a time for how late a message can be which I dont understand. How does the time I specify here affect the allowedLateness?

Comment: I've updated my response; hopefully that has made it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your patients but still not getting it. What happens then if the BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor time is much longer then the allowed lateness? So for example if you have BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor set to 50secounds and allowedLateness set to 10 seconds we would never wait 50 seconds? I think im missing some key insight to understand this.

Comment: So in my case where I use EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(10) it would go like this. First an event e arrives at t, then nothing will be triggered for BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor time for example 20seconds. Then after 20 seconds my window operator will trigger and collect events that are between t and t+20. After t+20 the end of window is reached but we still wait allowedLateness until we delete the session. Is this thinking right? And if so how are new events handled if the BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor is wrong and a new message actually arives after the period?

Comment: Sorry, but no, that's not right. And I fear my earlier comment was misleading, so I have deleted it. When I find time I'll expand the tutorial on watermarks to try to make the mechanism more transparent.