# intellij cant find Flink Test Harness util

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, apache-flink

I'm trying to use `OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness` from Apache Flink (org.apache.flink.streaming.util.OneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness) but Intellj can't resolve symbol.

I've followed the [offical docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/testing/), this offical [blog on the flink website](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/02/07/a-guide-for-unit-testing-in-apache-flink.html)
and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717003/how-to-utilize-flinks-testharness-class)

Comment: Have you tried to run reload in build tool window after adding dependencies?

Comment: Can you spell out in more detail what you've tried?

Comment: *but Intellj can't resolve symbol.* - which symbol? where is the code? how can we guess without seeing it?

Comment: I m having the same problem. I cannot find the TestHarness classes for flink-test-utils, flink-streaming-java, flink-runtime, and flink-test-utils-junit.

Answer (score 2):

When using Maven you will need the `<classifier>tests` tag on `flink-streaming-java`:

```xml
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-test-utils -->
        <!-- https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/datastream/testing/ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!-- NOTE mvn shows test scope -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-test-utils-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-test-utils-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!-- NOTE mvn shows test scope -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <!-- NOTE mvn shows test scope -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

You don't need the `flink-test-utils-junit` if you're using ScalaTest. I don't think you actually need runtime either (unless you use it elsewhere in your project), but I have tested the above (w/wo `flink-test-utils-junit`) and know it works for me.

Comment: Sort of wish that they'd document this stuff? I'm a Java / Flink newb, and I'm spending a lot of time on S/O for stuff that just isn't mentioned in the docs...

Answer (score 0):

In the [apache flink docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/testing/)

It says,

"Be aware that AbstractStreamOperatorTestHarness and its derived classes are currently not part of the public API and can be subject to change."

I have run into this issue before and have not come across any java artifacts that actually contain those classes.

Update:

TL;DR Build from source and include the jar directly.

Solution: Locate the flink source code from the github page for the correct version: https://github.com/apache/flink/releases/tag/release-x.xx

```
cd /path/to/flink-release-x.xx
unzip flink-release-x.xx.zip
```

unzip the file, and follow the instructions to build the project. This usually means running something like,

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

Ensure you are using the correct version for both maven and java. The maven version can usually be seen by looking in the pom.xml file for one of these two properties: maven.compiler.source or maven.compiler.target

If you are using the latest version, you can simply clone the entire project and use the maven build script. However, this didn't work for my case as I needed an earlier version.

Once built, the test harnesses are located in this jar: flink-release-x.xx/flink-streaming-java/target/flink-streaming-java-x.xx-tests.jar

You may also need to add the following runtime jar: flink-release-x.xx/flink-runtime/target/flink-runtime-x.xx.jar

You can add the jars to Intellij by going to, File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> "+" -> JARs or Directories

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try to add below to ur build.gradle's dependencies block:

```
testImplementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-test-utils_2.11:1.14.2'
testImplementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-runtime:1.14.2'
testImplementation 'org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.11:1.14.2:tests'
```

Reference: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/datastream/testing/

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, using SBT. I'm on Flink version '1.12.2' and scalaVersion '2.12'

```
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-test-utils" % flinkVersion % Test,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-streaming-java" % flinkVersion % Test,
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-runtime" % flinkVersion % Test,
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-test-utils-junit" % flinkVersion % Test
```

To add on to ender's answer, try adding "flink-test-utils-junit" as well.